# No syntax highlighting for .story file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, easyb

I'm using IntelliJ 10.5.4 with easyb-X plugin and Groovy 1.8.6 on one instance of the IDE where the syntax highlighting isn't working.  I initially got it working on a different system where the syntax highlighting was working.  When I disable the easyb plugin the syntax highlighting works (i.e. it uses the Groovy language highlighting which I believe it should).  Why is the easyb plugin overriding (and thereby disabling) the syntax highlighting?  I'd like to be able to run the easyb stories in the IDE *and* have the syntax highlighting... not one or the other.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the [IntelliJ forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity?view=discussions)?  That seems like a more appropriate place for this sort of question.

Comment: When I initially searched the forum no questions came up related to easyb.  I figured I stood a better chance in this forum. :-)

Comment: In what files highlghting does not work? *.groovy or *.story?

Answer (score 2):

Check your file type associations in File | Settings | File types -> Groovy files